# Passing parent value to simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a project and to add a service to the project I pass the project id to the service with:

```
new_service_path(project: "#{@id}")
```

My Services controller then finds the project:

```
  def new
    @service = Service.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project])
    @service.documents.build
  end
```

I can display the project in the view but I want to save the project Id to the Service record to create the association. I am using Simple Form with:

```
  simple_form_for @service do |f|
```

and this code works in the form:

```
   <% if @project %>
      <%= f.association :project, selected: @project.id %>
  <% else %>
      <%= f.association :project %>
  <% end %>
```

However if I have a project I want to skip the selection process created with the f.association and the select box and simply add the project_id to my Service object.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you set the Project to the Service in the controller?

```
  def new
    @service = Service.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project])
    if @project
      @service.project = @project
    end
    @service.documents.build
  end
```

Then the form for the Project is just:

```
<%= f.association :project %>
```

Anyways, you could pass along the Project ID into the next route when you submit the form, such as `simple_form_for @service, :url => create_project_path(project: @project.id) do |f|` and then accept that parameter and set that association in the `create` method:

```
  def new
    @service = Service.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project])
    @service.documents.build
  end

  def create
    @service = Service.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project])
    if @project
      @service.project = @project
    end
    # ... other logic
  end
```

Then just hide the `project` field like you've done in your question.

Hidden inputs may be another approach, but I don't think it's the best.